# JQuery autocomplete and MVC no suggestions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-autocomplete

I have problem with autocompleting text by JQuery.I used ChromeBug and everything looks fine. Text is sending into controller, there i put breakpoint to see what he get and wverything looks fine.
But in textbox i don't have any suggestion.

My controler looks like that:

```
public JsonResult AutocompleteTowns(string term) {
            return this.Json(db.Miastoes.Where(x => x.Nazwa.StartsWith(term)).ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

SCRIPT:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#nazwaMiasta').autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("AutocompleteTowns", "Administrator")'
        });
)};
```

Do You have any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved!
I didn't return string, I returned object of Miastoes type.

```
  public JsonResult AutocompleteTowns(string term) {
            var city = from c in db.Miastoes
                       where c.Nazwa.StartsWith(term)
                       select c.Nazwa;
            return this.Json(city, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```